# Parse Json in c# and create a class based on the schema

Tags: c#, json

I've created a set of rules in Json that comprise of regular expressions to sort emails.

I want to parse this file for each email object that I have created to pull matches. I've created a Field, Test and Case such as the following:

```
 [
        {
            "Field": "Subject",
            "Test": "^(Azure)", // this is my regex
            "Cases" : [
                {
                    "Field": "Content",
                    "Test": "Hostname: az.....(?<Hostname>[^\n])" //this is my regex
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
```

- I want to firstly be able to refer to this file in my c# program.
  Then I want to be able to reference my Field, Test and Case to use to apply to my email objects.
  So i could do something like the following:

  ```
  ProcessCase(Case case, Email email, Result result) {
     var value = email[case.field];
     if(!matches = Regex(case.test).matches) {
         return null;
     }
     foreach(var match in matches) {
         new Result(result.add(match.name, match.value))
     }
  ```

I thought that i should turn them into class, such as that in my rule class.

So I created a new class called Rules:

```
public class Rules{
            public string Field { get; set; }
            public string Test { get; set; } 
            public string Case { get; set; } 
            }
```

Then I read about Deserialized json:

```
   Rules myDeserializedObj = (Rules)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(Request["jsonString"], typeof(Rules));
```

Then I got a bit confused/stuck as to what to do next.

I'm not looking for code answers here really, more of how we firstly take a json file and can use the schema to create a rules class that can be used.

I hope this is clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Cases` would be an array of `Rules` - So, you should change from this in your class, `public string Case { get; set; }` to `public Rules[] Cases { get; set; }`, to refer to the file, you just need to read it from the disk, using `System.IO`

Comment: Json is the serialisation of an object. So there is an object definition that perfectly match it. https://app.quicktype.io?share=F0OeM580MQzP78ZIWg9m. There is a ton of tool that can do that from built int Visual studio special past in the edition menu. To Json2Csharp.com or App.QuickType.io

Comment: @Greg it also looks like you'll be deserializing into an array of Rules objects as your example JSON shows [] on the outer portion.

Comment: Yes I am. This is just a snapshot of the json but it's Rules with Rules

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused as how we actually get data out of a JSON. I've got a path to the file now thanks to @Ryan, but unsure how we then start to pull them. I'm guessing we'd just use a setter?

Comment: @Greg All JSON is, is a string representation of an object or array of objects, you would use `System.IO` to read in a file (text) into a string variable, then convert that (deserialize) it to the the proper class object or array of class objects. Then use a loop or whatever means you plan to use to test your regex(s). It looks like your JSON is structured to fit a Composite design pattern in your class design. Either a Rule contains more Rules or the Rules property will be `null` meaning it is a singular instance. `Newtonsoft.Json` is a popular `nuget` package for JSON ser/deser.

Comment: @Greg Here's a link to Newtonsoft docs: (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)